# Struts+ ehcache does not keep object all time

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I use ehcache in Struts application. I load cache while application is starting by CacheListener. Next if I want to get element from cache i use CacheExt. It working properly, but after some time this element from cache is `null`. Any ideas why ?

```
public class CacheListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        CacheExt.cm.addCache("cache");
        Cache cache = CacheExt.cm.getCache("cache");
        cache.put(new Element("USERS", new String[]{"User1", "Ala", "Zdzislaw"}));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        CacheExt.cm.shutdown();
    }
}

public class CacheExt {

    static CacheManager cm = CacheManager.getInstance();

    public static Element getCachedObject(String name) {
        Cache cache = cm.getCache("cache");
        return cache.get(name);
    }
}

public class ActionClass {
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String[])CacheExt.getCachedObject("USERS").getObjectValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your cache configuration?

Comment: If you use the same key the same object is returned.

Comment: What do you mean cache configuration ?